# Get Value in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the 2 months back date from today and display it in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Below is my code and it is giving value like this "Tue Feb 11 14:30:42 EST 2014"

```
   var d = new Date();
                    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 2);
                    $('#<%= txtStartDate.ClientID%>').val(d);
```

Comment: [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) will format it this way in the US locale by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I love MomentJS for date manipulation in Javascript. With it you can do this...

```
moment().subtract(2, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

and get back this `02/11/2014`

It's so easy to read too.

You can download MomentJS [here](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: No problem. It's what the site is for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 2); 
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today_date = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy
```

Try this code

Comment: i haven't downvoted, but: what happens with your code, if the month is 01? ;)

Comment: explain the reason who gave me downvote?

Comment: when your month will be 01?

Comment: var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 2);   this should work

Comment: this is better. your first solution doesn't work since it fails if the month is - e.g. - january (1 - (-2) = -1).

You might want to edit your answer and update it.

Comment: This is what I am having. Please check my first post